# What computers did the original Mac team use for development?

Tags: history, mac

There's a passage in Walter Isaacson's biography of Steve Jobs where Jobs moves Andy Hertzfeld to the Mac team by unplugging his computer and driving it over to the Mac building.

This got me wondering: what kind of computers did the Mac team use to develop software? Clearly it's a standalone machine, since it can be unplugged and physically moved, but I can't find any information about this.

Comment: Which Mac? There are a number of evolutions Apple's Mac OS has experienced. The current one is BSD-based.

Comment: The original Macintosh, in the early 1980's.

Comment: @JoshCaswell link leads to another story, [Black Wednesday](http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?project=Macintosh&story=Black_Wednesday.txt&sortOrder=Sort+by+Date&author=Andy+Hertzfeld), in which Andy Hertzfeld gives details about the context of his move and which computer it was that Steve Jobs unplugged and moved (an Apple II).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bruce Horn's article ["I Don't Have a Computer"](http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?project=Macintosh&story=I_Dont_Have_a_Computer!.txt&sortOrder=Sort+by+Date) on Folklore.org indicates that the Lisa was the development machine for the original Macintosh:

> I was ready to go, and I had been on the Mac team for several weeks but still hadn't gotten a Lisa, the development machine we used.

Comment: The Lisa, like the Mac, was 68K-based, and the 2/10 was eventually re-branded the Macintosh XL.

Comment: So, what computers did the original Lisa team use for development?

Comment: @mouviciel: [Apple II's first](http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?project=Macintosh&story=Well_See_About_That.txt&sortOrder=Sort+by+Date) ("Meanwhile, the Lisa team had been writing their first code in Pascal, running on Apple IIs, because the Lisa hardware wasn't ready yet."), then I believe they switched to using Lisas as well.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: this seems to provoke the obvious next question "what computers did the original Apple II team use for development" ;-)

Comment: @DocBrown - there's a great interview with the original Apple II "team" [here](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1430210788)

Comment: @DocBrown NeXT cubes brought back from the future :D

Comment: @DocBrown, maybe the Apple 1, but i dunno if they even had a computer running a cross-assembler for the 6502 microprocessor.  maybe the two Steves hand assembled the code for the Apple 1 and burned a 2708 EPROM directly with that.  (this is what i did with the 6800 and 6809 back in the late 70s.)

Comment: Damn, I knew it, Steve W. borrowed my Delorian when I visited him in 1976 ;-)